# How to Prove superposition principle for homogeneous linear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations

For the homogeneous linear system 
$$\mathbf x'(t)=A(t)\mathbf x(t)$$
a) Prove the superposition principle (i.e. linear combinations of solutions are solutions).

b) Show that it does not hold for an inhomogeneous system $$\mathbf x'(t)=A(t)\mathbf x(t)+ \mathbf f(t)$$

Comment: How about forming a linear combination of solutions and differentiating it?

Answer (score 2):

I will give you a partial solution by showing you how part (a) works.

If $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{y}$ are solutions to part (a), then just observe that for constants $c_1, c_2,$ $$(c_1\textbf{x}+c_2\textbf{y})'=c_1\textbf{x}'+c_2\textbf{y}'=c_1A\textbf{x}+c_2A\textbf{y}=A(c_1\textbf{x}+c_2\textbf{y}).$$ Try to see what happens if you follow the same process in part (b).